# Archive Opennebula images before transer and extract after

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, kvm

i have opennebula 3.4 and vm images transferred over ssh, it is possible to archive images(with gzip) and transfer to the host and then extract image?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new Transfer Manager. Read more here http://opennebula.org/documentation:rel3.4:sd